# NameError: name 'install' is not defined when installing packages using pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to create virtualenv and install project dependencies using pip.

```
$ mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages --distribute myenv
(myenv)$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I also set up `export VIRTUALENV_DISTRIBUTE=true` in `~/.bash_profile`

After installing some packages pip shows following error:

```
.....

Could not find the /Users/me/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/site.py element of the Setuptools distribution

Patched done.

Relaunching...

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

NameError: name 'install' is not defined

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /Users/me/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/me/.virtualenvs/myenv/build/distribute/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/r0/2b441j6x5rq8y964bhd15gkm0000gn/T/pip-wyn1Ys-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /Users/me/.virtualenvs/myenv/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /Users/me/.virtualenvs/myenv/build/distribute
```

Exactly the same happens without `--distribute` switch and without `export VIRTUALENV_DISTRIBUTE=true`

Here is my requirements.txt file:

```
Django==1.5
Pillow==1.7.6
South==0.7.3
amqplib==1.0.2
anyjson==0.3.1
celery==2.5.3
distribute==0.6.10
django-celery==2.4.2
django-indexer==0.3.0
django-kombu==0.9.4
django-mptt==0.5.2
django-paging==0.2.4
django-picklefield==0.2.1
django-social-auth==0.7.22
django-tagging==0.3.1
django-taggit==0.9.3
django-templated-email==0.4.7
django-templatetag-sugar==0.1
eventlet==0.9.16
greatape==0.3.0
greenlet==0.3.4
html5lib==0.90
httplib2==0.8
kombu==2.1.7
lockfile==0.9.1
oauth2==1.5.211
pycrypto==2.3
python-daemon==1.6
python-dateutil==1.5
python-openid==2.2.5
raven==1.0.4
sentry==2.0.0-RC6
simplejson==2.3.2
ssh==1.7.8
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

I am using `Mac OS X 10.9.2`.
I don't want to change anything in requirements.txt I just want to install all dependencies and run this project.

Comment: At what package does it fall over? Interestingly, `distribute` is among the required packages.

Comment: It fails on `Distribute` package

Comment: You set up `VIRTUALENV_DISTRIBUTE` in `.bashrc`, but did you source `.bashrc`? Otherwise the variable doesn't get set in your current shell.

Comment: I set up this var in `.bash_profile` and I opened new terminal... What do you mean by `source .bashrc`?

Comment: Have a read through http://askubuntu.com/questions/121073/why-bash-profile-is-not-getting-sourced-when-opening-a-terminal, in particular the accepted answer.

Comment: I did `source ~/.bash_profile` and `source ~/.bashrc` and it didn't help - I get the same error all the time

Comment: Could you try only installing distribute in your venv: `pip install 'distribute==0.6.10'` and edit your question with the result of that?

Comment: Actually I found answer somwhere - I just changed `distribute` version to `0.6.32` in requirements.txt and it works.

Comment: Hmm, that does contradict your statement " I don't want to change anything in requirements.txt".

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `distribute` package from the list, recreate your environment and reinstall the requirements.

You may remove the `wsgiref` as well (although not much important).

Comment: Kindly explain why installing 'distribute' is causing the error, as it may be helpful for upcoming site visitors.

Comment: http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/

"""
Distribute is a deprecated fork of the Setuptools project.

Since the Setuptools 0.7 release, Setuptools and Distribute have merged and Distribute is no longer being maintained. All ongoing effort should reference the Setuptools project and the Setuptools documentation.
"""